# Keyboard shortcut not working in yosemite

Tags: keyboard, macos, system-settings, shortcut

Here is the screen shot and it's not working anymore after upgrading to Yosemite
[image]

NOTE: **Although if I add this shortcuts under all applications then it works.**
I don't know why it's not working, wasted my time and I found on apple discussion forum that in Languages there should be only one language and that doesn't work for me.

Comment: It's your custom shortcut for Preview that's not working, yes? I'm having the exact same problem (though with a different menu item). I have other shortcuts for other apps that work fine, but Preview does not.

Comment: But thanks for the hint about the "All Applications" workaround -- I hadn't tried that.

Comment: Report the bug to Apple https://bugreport.apple.com/logon . This goes directly to apple engineering.

Comment: @cocoanut Reported :)

Comment: @InderKumarRathore I also filed a report. Mean while I'm using Keyboard Maestro, which is such a cool app anyway.

Answer (score 2):

I have reported this bug to apple and it's still not being closed. I will update my answer once it's closed.

**Till then you can add this shortcuts under all applications(instead of preview) then it will work.**

Comment: Such an annoying bug. I had to add my "Rename..." shortcut to All Applications instead of Preview.app

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why this isn't working either, but I ran into it with Mavericks too.

I've tried both "…" (proper ellipses) and "..." (three .) and neither of them work.

So I made a [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com/main/) macro for it instead:

[image: Screenshot of Keyboard Maestro macro, described below]

The key here is that the "Group" (labeled "1") is set up to only be active in Preview.app.

Then the macro (labeled 2) is where we explain what we want to have happen.

The "Trigger" (3) in this case is the same keyboard shortcut (aka "hot key") ⌘ ⇧ Z but could be anything

Then the action is to trigger the menu item Tools ---> Adjust Size...

(The "Stop macro is menu cannot be selected" might seem superfluous since there are no more actions after this one, however, if that happens, Keyboard Maestro will show an error to the user, which can be helpful. Otherwise it just silently fails.)

You can [download my Keyboard Maestro macro here](http://files.luo.ma/keyboardmaestro/preview-adjust-size.kmmacros.zip). Unzip it, double click on it to import it into Keyboard Maestro, and it will create the "Preview only" group and add the macro to it.

I still don't know why the official Keyboard Shortcut doesn't work in Preview.app, but an added bonus of using Keyboard Maestro is that since it can sync (using iCloud Drive or Dropbox), you can have it on all of your Macs. Keyboard Shortcuts added to the OS X System Preferences don't sync. Yet another reason I like Keyboard Maestro.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but personally I don't like third party sw for the task that can be done using in built applications.

Comment: I can understand that. (Of course, in this case, it _can't_ be done using the built-in application, but I get your meaning.) Having my keyboard shortcuts sync is definitely worth the reliance on a 3rd party app that I'd definitely insist on installing on any Mac I plan to use for any meaningful length of time!

Comment: Thanks Luoma.. I will surely try if I can't find the solution :)

Comment: This is a good suggestion. Keyboard Maestro is brilliant. I'm having the same issue in many applications.

Answer (score 0):

I had a shortcut in Mavericks (<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) to bring up the Tags box in Finder. Yosemite killed it, whether All Applications or Finder. Apple Support could not solve it, however I discovered that it will work if set to <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> instead.

Comment: Option shortcuts are normally used for special characters on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

If using keyboard with number pad use the numbers on the top not the number pad.  Don't know why it is different but it works for me using the numbers on top.